# Laravel logging with Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5, monolog

How can **Laravel 5**'s logging be changed to `Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler`?

What **doesn't** work in Laravel 5 but **does** work in a standalone PHP file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;    
use Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

// create a log channel
$log = Log::getMonolog();
// $log = new Logger('Testlogger'); //doesn't make any difference
$log->pushHandler(new BrowserConsoleHandler(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::INFO));

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

All that happens is that my logs appear in the logfile but don't find their way to the browser. If I try the code in a single PHP file without framework it works, so I assume it's a Laravel problem.

I get it working with Firebug and FirePHP installed and `$log->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());` instead of `BrowserConsoleHandler` but this is not a solution since it sends the logs with headers but I already sent some debug-echos when the logger wants to send the headers.
`BrowserConsoleHandler` on the other hand adds a JavaScript snippet to the end of the site that perfectly fits my needs.

So, did anyone succeed in adding `BrowserConsoleHandler` to Laravel's logging? How?

Comment: Where is this standalone file and how is it being loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading plenty of source code and getting xdebug to work I finally figuered it out:

`BrowserConsoleHandler` sends the script snipped after finishing the php script by `register_shutdown_function()`. At this time, Laravel already sent the full response to the browser. So the script snipped from `BrowseConsoleHandler` gets generated but never sent to the browser.

As a workaround you can build your own `Middleware` (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) that invokes the code generation manually and adds it to the response before it gets sent.

Create *app/Http/Middleware/LogBrowserConsole.php*:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler;

class LogBrowserConsole implements Middleware {

  public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
  {
    // add BrowserConsoleHandler to Laravel's Logger
    $log = Log::getMonolog();
    $log->pushHandler(new BrowserConsoleHandler(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::INFO));

    // invokes all your stuff like it would do without the middleware but with the new logger
    $response = $next($request);

    // after the request is done we care about the log entries
    $handlers = $log->getHandlers();

    $scriptSnippet = "";
    foreach($handlers as $handler){ // only handle BrowserConsoleHandler
        if($handler instanceof BrowserConsoleHandler){
            ob_start(); //start output buffer so we can save echo to variable
            $handler->send(); // create the scriptSnipped
            $scriptSnippet .= ob_get_clean();
        }
    }

    // write scriptSnippet to end of response content
    $content = $response->getContent();
    $response->setContent($content.$scriptSnippet);

    return $response;
  }
}
```

Register the Middleware in *app/Http/Kernel.php*:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'log.browserconsole' => 'App\Http\Middleware\LogBrowserConsole'
];
```

and invoke your Controller with the Middleware in *app/Http/routes.php*:

```
Route::get('test', ['middleware' => 'log.browserconsole', 'uses'=>'TestController@test']);
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to use the `Middleware` for every request you can add it to

```
protected $middleware = [
'App\Http\Middleware\LogBrowserConsole'
];
```

in *app/Http/Kernel.php*.

Your Route would look like `Route::get('test', 'TestController@test');`

---

Now, your `Log::debug()` etc. messages get sent to the logfile (the default LogHandler is still available, you just added another) and the script snipped from `BrowserConsoleHandler` gets built and sent to the browser with all your log items.

Keep in mind to eventually change the log level `\Psr\LogLevel::INFO` in *app/Http/Middleware/LogBrowserConsole* to fit your needs.