# Set up Monolog in Laravel global middleware

Tags: php, laravel, monolog, laravel-middleware

In my local environment I want all logs (all flags) to go the browser's console (`BrowserConsoleHandler`) and then to the default `StreamHandler`.
In production, I want the errors and other critical messages to go to an e-mail then stored in the database or (if fails) to a log file (default `StreamHandler`)

I want to set up this in a global middle-ware that I have created, which looks like this now:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler;

class GlobalConfig
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Get Monolog instance
        $monolog = Log::getMonolog();
        // In local environment the logs will be shown on browser
        if (App::environment('local')) {
            // Show logs in browser console
            $monolog -> pushHandler(new BrowserConsoleHandler());
        } else {
            // Here we set up for production
        }

        Log::debug("Browser handler working");

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work (the message is stored in the log file only, not shown on console). What I can't figure out is how to let the `Log` facade know about this new handler, because here, as is obvious, things are only changed within the function's scope. I know I can do it in `bootstrap/app.php` but isn't it to early to get the environment? Also, if I need to save logs to the database, it must already be connected, I guess

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do next in bootstrap\app.php

```
if(env('APP_ENV') == 'local') {
    $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) use ($app) {

         $monolog->pushHandler(
            $handler = new \Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(
                $app->storagePath().'/logs/laravel.log', 
                $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 30), 
                \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG
            )
        );

        $handler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));

        $monolog->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\NativeMailerHandler(
            'to@mail.com', 
            'Log::error!', 
            'from@mail.com'
        ));
    });
}
```

Idea here is to fully control your logging on live/local. Bad news - configureMonologUsing replace all default laravel loggers, so you need to configure all your logs manually here.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware isn't really the place for this, unless you wanted to actually make a particular log entry at some point in the request cycle.

Your call to `pushHandler` belongs in `bootstrap/app.php` (in Laravel 5.2), according to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration).

I would think it would be possible to extract this logic out into a provider in case it becomes complicated and you need to move it out of `bootstrap/app.php`

Answer (score 0):

[solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455996/laravel-logging-with-monolog-handler-browserconsolehandler)

> BrowserConsoleHandler sends the script snipped after finishing the php
>   script by register_shutdown_function(). At this time, Laravel already
>   sent the full response to the browser. So the script snipped from
>   BrowseConsoleHandler gets generated but never sent to the browser.